# Join across different databases on different servers in Doctrine and PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, join, doctrine

is there a way to do what dblink does in Doctrine?

I need to join two tables from two databases on two servers and don't want to use RawSql, but using models.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

What you're wanting is not "technically" supported as a design feature in Doctrine.

So if you're wanting to do this as you would with traditional PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2, table2.field2, 
    FROM table1 INNER JOIN 
        dblink('dbname=db2 port=5432 host=domainname2 
                user=someuser password=somepwd',
                'SELECT field1, field2,
                FROM other_table')
            AS table2(field1 int, field2 char(25))
        ON table1.field3 = table2.field1;
```

You would replace the single connection that's default in your config.php file with two connections.

```
<?php

Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://root@server1/doctrine_db1', 'db1');
Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://root@server2/doctrine_db2', 'db2');
```

Then you'd modify your schema with something like this:

```
---
Table1:
    tableName: db1.table1
    connection: db1
    columns:
        filed1: integer
        field2: string(255)
        field3: integer
    relations:
        Table2:
        foreignType: one
        onDelete: CASCADE

Table2:
    tableName: db2.table2
    connection: db2
    columns:
        field1: integer
        field2: string(25)
```

Then you'd build the database after adding data like normal. Then just do your regular modeling, making sure to specify the table with the field you want like you would with any regular query.

[Doctrine Cross Database Joins](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/cross-database-joins) are discussed in detail on the Doctrine blog. So you might check it out.

Comment: The correct link to the Doctrine blog entry mentioned above is :

http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/cross-database-joins.html

I tried editing the post to correct the link but it fell short of the minimum '6' characters required for the edit.